# Как получить список всех видео на канале?

Tags: youtube-api

С месяц назад, подобного рода  запрос http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/threedaysfaq/uploads выдавал фиды последних 25 видеозаписей, сейчас же показывает только ссылку на видео с надписью devicesupport и значком "кислой мины". Что изменилось и как быть?

Comment: youtube с недавних пор выпиливает [поддержку флеша в пользу html5](http://habrahabr.ru/company/eset/blog/249041/), возможно, в этом кроется причина.

Comment: @romeo может подскажете как получить список всех видеозаписей с конкретного канала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внимательно посмотреть видео, на которое приходит ссылка, то можно увидеть надпись на нескольких языках, включая русский:

> Приложение Youtube будет обновлено до версии, которую не поддерживает это устройство. Подробнее читайте на странице https://youtube.com/devicesupport

Если перейти по этой ссылке, можно узнать, что с апреля 2015 года приложение YouTube недоступно на некоторых устройствах в связи с обновлением версии Youtube Data API и, соответственно, прекращением поддержки старой версии. Также на этой странице приведена ссылка на [статью](http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3_4.html), в которой описывается процесс миграции на новую версию API.

Тот способ получения загруженных видео, которым пользуетесь вы, устарел и больше не работает. [Здесь](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos-retrieve-uploads) Google даёт рекомендации по переводу этой операции на новую версию API (смотрите в разделе Videos).

Comment: я имею ввиду запрос из браузера в адресной строке, все остальные запросы ( получение информации о канале, список плэйлистов) не изменили своего поведения.

Comment: Вы хоть почитайте, что пишет Google по этому поводу. Тот способ получения загруженных видео, которым пользуетесь вы, устарел и больше не работает. [Здесь](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos-retrieve-uploads) Google даёт рекомендации по переводу этой операции на новую версию API (смотрите в разделе Videos).

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ!